# JSON format for flutter http

Tags: php, mysqli, flutter

long story short, I input some `json_object` into mysql database. Using PHP I created a Http for my flutter project. However I am getting the error showing:

```
FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 7, character 26)
        "attributes": "{"screen": "50 inch", "resolution": "2048 x 1152 pix...
                         ^
```

My php code to http

```
$search = "SELECT * FROM `database`.`products` 
            WHERE `category_id` = 1 
            AND JSON_EXTRACT(`attributes` , '$.ports.usb') > 0 
            AND JSON_EXTRACT(`attributes` , '$.ports.hdmi') > 0;";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $search);

if ($result) {
    //Printing out the details of the rows

    while($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $jsonData[]=$array;
    }

    $nonArr = json_encode($jsonData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    $stringArr = (string)$nonArr;
    $nonSlash = str_replace("\\","", $stringArr);
    echo $nonSlash;
}  

mysqli_close($link)
```

Here what the http is showing

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Prime",
        "brand_id": "1",
        "category_id": "1",
        "attributes": "{"screen": "50 inch", "resolution": "2048 x 1152 pixels", "ports": {"hdmi": 1, "usb": 3}, "speakers": {"left": "10 watt", "right": "10 watt"}}"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Octoview",
        "brand_id": "1",
        "category_id": "1",
        "attributes": "{"screen": "40 inch", "resolution": "1920 x 1080 pixels", "ports": {"hdmi": 1, "usb": 2}, "speakers": {"left": "10 watt", "right": "10 watt"}}"
        }
]
```

looks good? Not so..

The flutter project is only working when I use the url pointing to a json file in my cpanel example, something.json file and I typed every line out as shown below:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Prime",
        "brand_id": "1",
        "category_id": "1",
        "attributes": [{"screen": "50 inch", "resolution": "2048 x 1152 pixels", "ports": {"hdmi": 1, "usb": 3}, "speakers": {"left": "10 watt", "right": "10 watt"}]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Octoview",
        "brand_id": "1",
        "category_id": "1",
        "attributes": [{"screen": "40 inch", "resolution": "1920 x 1080 pixels", "ports": {"hdmi": 1, "usb": 2}, "speakers": {"left": "10 watt", "right": "10 watt"}}]
        }
]
```

As you can see, the difference is only the change of " " to [ ].
Any pro out there mind showing me how can I get this result?

Comment: `"{"` is illegal I think. Are you building JSON String manually?

Comment: You had better check how you store this JSON String to the database, thats where your error is

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Hi! Thanks for the reply! I created my the database by copying this web page. Is this method wrong?https://www.google.com.sg/amp/s/scotch.io/amp/tutorials/working-with-json-in-mysql